# Two sum leetcode solution

Tags: java

Задачка с [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), найти в массиве значения суммы двух элементов которых равны определенному числу.
Например int[] nums = {1,3,4,5}; int target = 8. Элементы 3 и 5(индексы в массиве 1 и 3).
Стандартное решение с помощью циклов:

```
 public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    }
```

Вариант с использованием Map:

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] result = new int[2];
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int difference = target - nums[i];
            if (map.containsKey(difference)){
                result[0] = i;
                result[1] = map.get(difference);
                return result;
            }
            map.put(nums[i], i);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Но стало интерсно что есть еще одно решение которое является самым быстрым:

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int MOD = 2047;
        int arr[] = new int[2048];
        int len=nums.length;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            int key = target - nums[i] & MOD;
            if(arr[key]!=0)
            {
                return new int[]{arr[key]-1,i};
            }
            arr[nums[i] & MOD]=i+1;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Кто нибудь может пояснить зачем определяем int = 2047 и массив на 2048 элементов?

Comment: По твоему вопросу не совсем понятно, что ты имеешь ввиду. Если код работает правильно, то непонятно в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не решение задачи а уловка.
Данная программа написана в предположении, что никто не проверит её на больших числах. Видимо автор решил, что 2048 - достаточно большое число.
Программа работает правильно для чисел в диапазоне 0 - 2047.
2047 - это верхний индекс массива размером 2048.